# how to return only HTTP Status code, if we hit one pre-defined endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http-status

When I hit

```
@FeignClient(name = "abc_abc", url = "${abc.host}")
public interface validateClient {

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/abc/validate",
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json")
    **public <?>  validateResponse**(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders htppHeaders, @RequestParam Map<String, Object> params,
                                                 @RequestBody String request);
}
```

in this example API: **/api/abc/validate**
i just want to return only HTTP status code
what is the return type of **validateResponse** method ? please some one plz suggest

Comment: may be if it is only port you can use Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try use ResponseEntity without any "body", here an example.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api/abc/validate",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity validateResponse(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders htppHeaders, @RequestParam Map<String, Object> params,
                                             @RequestBody String request) {
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).build();
}
```

You can choose from standard HttpStatus enum, or simply insert an integer for your custom needs

Comment: in this case we were getting only ResponseEntity , but not output json payload.
Example : 
 validateResponse(-,-,-) method returns output like below
 {
"id": "201",

Comment: isn't that what you've been looking for? As I understood your question you wanted your response to have empty body and show the result of your operation **ONLY** with a statusCode. If you want to response with any kind of body you just need to place it here: `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).body(anyObjectThatYouLike)`;